Clothes and other house/household chores kids learning playing and attention making app (supporting different households)
I am looking for a game that allows you to embed yourself in the whole procedure related to the clothes business, as lived by a person who needs to manage everything relating to clothes for their household.
In the game, household members go out and consume clothes or grow and the clothes need to be repurchased online or outdoors in shops and markets, and may arrive at home or at the post office in which case they may be picked up.
They may even be custom designed and made by custom factories and shops to whom you send the custom orders.
This is part of the game.
People dress, and may need to get dressed.
This is part of the game.
When clothes get dirty, people place the clothes on the stairs (and change). They may get dirty because they are old, people went to sleep or not, with the clothes, or simply, a day passed, or they sweated, or dropped things onto themselves while carrying them, or eating, or washing stuff like hands in the bathroom or dishes in the sink in which case water may have fallen onto them. Food may have fallen onto the clothes because a napkin was not placed or perhaps snot fell onto a shirt or trousers from the nose or perhaps spit from drool from the mouth, or perhaps the person was eating standing and food feel onto the clothes.
This is part of the game.
The other part of the game is the pipeline. Clothes are placed on the stairs when dirty. When the person goes up the stairs they take the dirty clothes and put them in the bathroom in the baskets. If the baskets are full they place them on the floor.
This is part of the game.
The clothes go into the washing machine. The washing powder must be ready. If not, they must go to a store that has it trying stores in turn, to purchase the washing powder. Some washing solution might damage the hands and the user must be careful to purchase the correct one.
This is part of the game.
When the clothes in the washing machine finish, they go in the dryer placed above the dryer.
So, the washing machine becomes empty, and more clothes must be placed in if available.
No dirty clothes will be waiting on the stairs because the user grabs then and brings them upstairs when they go up the stairs to the washing machine and dryer.
This is part of the game.
When the sun is out, the clothes go out instead of in the dryer. The user must districate them with a hit or blow and then put them onto the wires.
Is it is raining, the user must put them indoors.
This is part of the game.
The user must look at the time and not use the appliances during times designated as more expensive from an electricity consuming charge point of view.
This is part of the game.
The clothes dry, and the user folds the clothes.
The clothes are separated into plies according to clothes users, and are then placed in each place belonging to reach user acceptingly.
The user must recognize the clothes by size and format, and, initially, the game suggests who owns the clothes. Next time the user plays they must do this by themselves.
The next part of the pipeline is placing the clothes in the drawers and in the wardrobe.
This is part of the game.
The floor may become dirty because in the clothes dirtying process the floor got dirty.
The user cleans it with broom and broom cloth or mop, taking the dirty away from the cloth with soap, districating the cloth with the soap to take off the dirt in the sink, rinsing, and twisting the cloth to make the water fine out of the cloth.
This is part of the game.
As part of the game, users would select the right clothes cycle for cycles of dark, light, or mixed colors clothes that could also bekong to different laundry baskets advising to such category or share a basket of there were less baskets than category types in which case they must be separated later prior to putting them in the washer.
This is part of the game.
After some bedding items are washed and perhaps died, they must be placed onto doors for drying.
Before beds are made the blankets must be shaken/hit onto the balcony to get the dirt and dust off and left a bit there to dry out.
This is part of the game.
The same goes for the pillows.
This is part of the game.
Pegs may fall or clothes may fall or pegs may break and enough pegs must be placed so that the weight of the clothes or blankets and wind does not take the clothes away.
The user may repurchase pegs if gone.
This is in the game.
You could even extend this game to cooking (/list making, shopping), tidying, and cleaning the bathrooms.
Even to window closing to prevent wind from breaking them or their glass, and glass repairing in such case, and heat preservation and regulation through hearing equipment or wood based chimneys.
So, I think, and I believe, that this would be a nice game on Android to go though all the steps, and, mentally, do, and get familiar with  memorize, gain experience, without doing all the effort, but memorizing the steps, IN ORDER TO GAIN INDEPENDENCE AND PRACTICITY/PRACTICALITY IN THE HOUSEHOLD THOUGH THE SMARTPHONE
.
The game, could support difference procedures and pipelines to support different households.
Kids could gain awareness of house chores and gain practicality and learn while playing (the game, on Android).
It would be good.
Thanks.
